# Solving a modular exponentiation with unknown power

Tags: c++, exponentiation, modular

Guys I what is the fastest algorithm to solve a modular equation in the format of `a^b = c mod p` where `p` is a really big prime and `b` is unknown.
e.g.:

```
2^k = 15 mod 30903154482632612361920641803533
```

I already tried trial and error using boost library in C++ but it would take very long time to reach the answer.

Comment: That seems to be the whole point of public key cryptography. It would take a very long time to crack it.

Comment: Yes I know but it should not take a long time for the example I provided as my lecturer give it to solve and he told it should not take so much time

Comment: I just need the most efficient algorithm for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to solve what is called a [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). If there was an efficient solution to this, I imagine whoever discovered it would wreak chaos on cryptographic systems long before it would be posted here.

You will find quite a couple of [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) on Wikipedia with varying time complexity. Some of these are quite easy to implement. See [The computational complexity of discrete log](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48767/the-computational-complexity-of-discrete-log) for the best space complexity.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information but does it differ if p is prime or not? which one is simpler to deal with?